# Conditionally split array based on sequence logic using ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have an array of photos, each of which has an `aspectRatio`. I’d like to split the array into smaller arrays of different lengths dependant on the `aspectRatio`.

```
const photos = [
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 1.5 } },
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 1.5 } },
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 0.67 } },
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 0.67 } },
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 0.67 } },
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 0.67 } },
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 1.5 } },
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 1.5 } },
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 0.67 } }
]
```

In this case, I’d like to to split the array every 2 items by default, and then into 3 items when there’s 3 items of `aspectRatio < 1` in a row.

What I’d like to be left with is this:

```
const result = [
  [
    { fluid: { aspectRatio: 1.5 } }, 
    { fluid: { aspectRatio: 1.5 } }
  ],
  [
    { fluid: { aspectRatio: 0.67 } },
    { fluid: { aspectRatio: 0.67 } },
    { fluid: { aspectRatio: 0.67 } },
  ],
  [
    { fluid: { aspectRatio: 0.67 } }, 
    { fluid: { aspectRatio: 1.5 } }
  ],
  [
    { fluid: { aspectRatio: 1.5 } }, 
    { fluid: { aspectRatio: 0.67 } }
  ],
]
```

I’ve looked at using `splitWhen`, however it only seems to work on the current item without being able to look ahead in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Ramda has anything to help here.  My thought would be to do this recursively:

```js
const group = (ps, rs = []) => ps.length == 0
  ? rs
  : ps.length < 3
    ? rs.concat([ps])
    : ps.slice(0, 3).every(p => p.fluid.aspectRatio < 1)
      ? group(ps.slice(3), rs.concat([ps.slice(0, 3)]))
      : group(ps.slice(2), rs.concat([ps.slice(0, 2)]))

const photos = [{fluid: {aspectRatio: 1.5}}, {fluid: {aspectRatio: 1.5}}, {fluid: {aspectRatio: 0.67}}, {fluid: {aspectRatio: 0.67}}, {fluid: {aspectRatio: 0.67}}, {fluid: {aspectRatio: 0.67}}, {fluid: {aspectRatio: 1.5}}, {fluid: {aspectRatio: 1.5}}, {fluid: {aspectRatio: 0.67}}]

console.log(group(photos))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to iterate the array, and add a new sub-array to the accumulator, according to the rules you've presented. Always push the current item to the last sub-array:

```js
const photos = [{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":1.5}},{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":1.5}}, {"fluid":{"aspectRatio":1.5}},{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":0.67}},{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":0.67}},{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":0.67}},{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":0.67}},{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":1.5}},{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":1.5}},{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":0.67}}]

const allAspectsUnder1 = arr => arr.every(o => o.fluid.aspectRatio < 1)

const result = photos.reduce((r, o) => {
  const last = r[r.length - 1]

  if (!last ||
    last.length === 3 ||
    (last.length === 2 && !allAspectsUnder1(last))
  ) r.push([])

  r[r.length - 1].push(o)

  return r
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

And this is the equivalent idea in Ramda:

```js
const { pipe, length, equals, allPass, any, pathSatisfies, lt, last, anyPass,  isNil, reduce, ifElse, init } = R

const lengthEquals = len => pipe(length, equals(len))

const length2AndLargeAspects = allPass([
  lengthEquals(2),
  any(pathSatisfies(lt(1), ['fluid', 'aspectRatio'])),
])

const shouldAddSub = pipe(
  last,
  anyPass([
    isNil,
    length2AndLargeAspects,
    lengthEquals(3),
  ])
)

const fn = reduce(ifElse(
  shouldAddSub, 
  (a, o) => [...a, [o]],
  (a, o) => [...init(a), [...last(a), o]],
), [])

const photos = [{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":1.5}},{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":1.5}}, {"fluid":{"aspectRatio":1.5}},{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":0.67}},{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":0.67}},{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":0.67}},{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":0.67}},{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":1.5}},{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":1.5}},{"fluid":{"aspectRatio":0.67}}]

const result = fn(photos)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a simple `do/while` loop. Slice sub arrays by 3's  and check if any are greater than one and pop back to 2  if there are

```js
let res=[], sIdx = 0;

do {

 const arr = photos.slice(sIdx, sIdx + 3); 
 if(arr.length > 2 && arr.some(({ fluid:{aspectRatio}}) => aspectRatio >= 1 ) ){
    arr.pop();
 }
 res.push(arr);
 sIdx += arr.length;
 
} while ( sIdx < photos.length)

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important;}
```

```html
<script>

const photos = [
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 1.5 } },
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 1.5 } },
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 0.67 } },
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 0.67 } },
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 0.67 } },
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 0.67 } },
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 1.5 } },
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 1.5 } },
  { fluid: { aspectRatio: 0.67 } }
]

</script>
```